# How do I modify song info (e.g. ID3 Tags, AAC info) on songs that are in the media library?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I'm building an app that will fetch updated data about the current song online, and I'd like it to fill in some blank fields on the song (e.g. year, genre).

Is there any way to do this using the iOS SDK?  The only other option I can think of is writing a desktop application to do it, but I'd rather keep it on the devise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not positive, but I don't think Apple allows you to edit the user's library data.

Comment: There are no exposed APIs that allow you to modify the tag information on media that is in the library - I think it doesn't actually read the information from the files, but from the 'media library' that it builds after syncing the device

Comment: Agreed - I couldn't read any tag info off the m4a files dumped by libimobiledevice. Maybe a little Ot since the question was about an iOS SDK, but the library is in the file iTunes_Control/iTunes/iTunes Library.itlp/Library.itdb and it's a regular SQLite file that you can open with sqliteman.  Maybe there's an iOS way to get to it from that angle?

Comment: Agreed - Since the sandbox concept, programmers have no way to access the music library with file layer.

Hence, we do not have chance to access file format. So, Apple did not provide any framework/SDK to change the music library, we cannot modify the metadata.